# Ruby and the uniq method

Tags: ruby, arrays

I don't get this:

```
2.0.0-p598 :003 > a=[1,2,3]
 => [1, 2, 3] 
2.0.0-p598 :004 > (a << 1).uniq!
 => [1, 2, 3] 
2.0.0-p598 :005 > a
 => [1, 2, 3]
```

I don't understand why a is actually modified. I would guess that the parentheses would make the uniq method work on everything in the parentheses and not the variable. Can someone explain?

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, `uniq!` (unlike `uniq`) returns `nil` if the receiver (the array) is not altered: `a = [1,2,3]`, `a.uniq! => nil`, but `a => [1,2,3]`, so writing, for example, `[1,2,3].uniq!.map { |i| i*2 }` would be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C)

```
a << 1
```

returns `a` itself.

Your code modifies the array twice.

First `1` is pushed to the array `a` and `a` is returned from `(a << 1)` as a result. Then you call `uniq!` on it.

Here's what the code does step by step, without chaining:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [1, 2, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):002:0> a << 1
=> [1, 2, 3, 1]
irb(main):003:0> a
=> [1, 2, 3, 1]
irb(main):004:0> a.uniq!
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):005:0> a
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Notice that the method has an exclamation mark (bang!) at the end of its name. This is a naming convention for methods in Ruby that modify the object they're called on. You could use `uniq` instead of `uniq!` and have the `a` array unmodified.

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [1, 2, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):002:0> a << 1
=> [1, 2, 3, 1]
irb(main):003:0> a
=> [1, 2, 3, 1]
irb(main):004:0> a.uniq
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):005:0> a
=> [1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Great - thanks. That makes sense. I know about bang methods - I just couldn't see how the method got to a. But you explained that. Thanks!